# How to handle Hold event or Load event of an item inside LongListSelector

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a LongListSelector and use binding.

When the user selects an Item in LongListSelector, I handle the `SelectionChanged` event of it and access it this way:

```
var selectedItem = MyListSelector.SelectedItem as NumbersViewModel;
```

But I want to to something when the user holds an Item of LongListSelector or an Item is loaded for the first time,

Can I handle such that events? (it is WP8)

Answer (score 0):

You can raise [ManipulationStarted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.uielement.manipulationstarted%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) & [ManipulationCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.uielement.manipulationcompleted%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) events on that item (object in LongListSelector) for Hold event purpose. Hope this will help you.